# Ruby sub hash comparison

Tags: ruby

So I have a hash of hashes....

```
 @win_moves = {
    :wm01 => {:a1=>"X", :a2=>" ", :a3=>" ", :b1=>" ", :b2=>"X", :b3=>" ", :c1=>" ", :c2=>" ", :c3=>"X"},
    :wm02 => {:a1=>" ", :a2=>"X", :a3=>" ", :b1=>" ", :b2=>"X", :b3=>" ", :c1=>" ", :c2=>"X", :c3=>" "},
    :wm03 => {:a1=>" ", :a2=>" ", :a3=>"X", :b1=>" ", :b2=>"X", :b3=>" ", :c1=>"X", :c2=>" ", :c3=>" "},
    :wm04 => {:a1=>" ", :a2=>" ", :a3=>" ", :b1=>"X", :b2=>"X", :b3=>"X", :c1=>" ", :c2=>" ", :c3=>" "},
    :wm05 => {:a1=>"X", :a2=>"X", :a3=>"X", :b1=>" ", :b2=>" ", :b3=>" ", :c1=>" ", :c2=>" ", :c3=>" "},
    :wm06 => {:a1=>" ", :a2=>" ", :a3=>" ", :b1=>" ", :b2=>" ", :b3=>" ", :c1=>"X", :c2=>"X", :c3=>"X"}
  }
```

and I want to take a hash like such..

```
@thegrid = {:a1=>"X", :a2=>"O", :a3=>" ", :b1=>"O", :b2=>"X", :b3=>" ", :c1=>" ", :c2=>" ", :c3=>"X"}
```

and compare it to the previous hash @win_moves for the X values so I would get a positive match on  @win_moves[0] (the answer in this case)...I need to check for the presence of the X.

Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: Is it on purpose that \@thegrid contains "O" and \@win_moves contains " "?

Comment: yes. I need to test against the location of the X's regardless of empty spaces or the presence of O's.

Comment: We also need to know what you need in return.  Do you need to know which one matched or just that one did match?

Comment: either...but for simplicity...just that one did match

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't mind being destructive of your @thegrid hash you can do the following:

```
@winmoves.has_value? @thegrid.each { |k, v| thegrid[k] = " " if v == "O" }
```

That will return true if any of the keys in your winmoves are matched.  Ff you need to do it non-destructively the following should work:

```
a_new_hash = @thegrid.inject({}) { |h, (k, v)| h[k] = " " if v == "O"; h }
@winmoves.has_value? a_new_hash
```

Answer (score 0):

The following would find all keys in @win_moves that have the matching Xs as @thegrid:

```
keys_with_x = @thegrid.select{ |k, v| v == "X" }.keys
matching_moves = @win_moves.select{ |k, v| v.select{ |k, v| v == "X" }.keys == keys_with_x }
puts matching_moves.keys
#=> wm01
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do that:

```
@win_moves.any?{|k,v| v.reject{|a,b| b != 'X'} == @thegrid.reject{|c,d| d!= 'X'}}
```